# How can I write $f(x)=m +o(1/x)$

Tags: real-analysis

In a book in is written

> Let $f(x)$ tends to $m$ not equal to 0 as $x$ tends to infinity. Then $f(x)= m+o(1/x)$ where $o(1/x)$ means terms containing $1/x$ and its higher powers.

How can we write $f(x)= m+o(1/x)$?
Please elaborate this

Comment: Do you mean $$\lim_{x->inf}f(x)=m$$

Comment: Yes. f(x) tends to m( not =0) as x tends to infinity

Comment: Examples like $f(x)=1+1/(1+\sqrt{|x|}$ show this is obviously false. as stated  Maybe there are some extra unstated assumptions about $f$?

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)-m = o(1/x)$ means $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{|f(x) - m|}{1/x} = 0.$$

The above statement is **not** implied by $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = m$. For example you can show that $f(x) = m + 1/x$ or $f(x) = m + 1/\sqrt{x}$ fail to satisfy the above statement.

Comment: f: R to R continuous fn such that integration 0 to infinity f(x)dx exist. This is given information.

Comment: What is o(1/x)?

Comment: @Algebra Algebra See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation

Comment: Thank you very much brother.

Answer (score 0):

Take $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+1$$
then

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=1$$

but

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)-1}{\frac 1x}\ne 0$$

thus
$$f(x)-1 \ne o(\frac 1x)$$